# Show that $c$ is closed in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $$c=\{ (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \ ; \ \ a_i \in \mathbb{R}\ ,\ \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \ , \ \mbox{exist} \ \displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty}(a_i)\}$$
 $$l^{\infty}=\{ (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \ ; \ a_i \in \mathbb{R}\ ,\ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}; \  \displaystyle \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|a_i|< \infty \}.$$ Show that $c$ is closed in $l^{\infty}$.

i am trying... taking a sequence of sequence in $c$ but i can't...i show that $c_0$ is closed in $l^{\infty}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: i am trying... taking a sequence of sequence in $c$ but i can't...i show that $c_0$ is closed in $l^{\infty}$.

Comment: If you know that $c_0$ is closed in $l^\infty$, just use the fact that the sum of a closed subspace and a finite-dimensional subspace is closed. $c = c_0 + \text{constant sequences}$

Comment: i don't know this result...but thanks ^_^

Comment: @Martin what is it result... help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \ell^{\infty} & \to & \mathbb{R} \\ (x_n) & \mapsto & \limsup\limits_{n \to + \infty} x_n \end{array} \right.$ and $g : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \ell^{\infty} & \to & \mathbb{R} \\ (x_n) & \mapsto & \liminf\limits_{n \to + \infty} x_n \end{array} \right.$.

Show that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and deduce that $c= \{ x \in \ell^{\infty} \mid f(x)=g(x) \}$ is closed in $\ell^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is closed if and only if for any sequence $a_n\in A$ converging to an $x\in X$ you have $x\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Convergence in $\ell_\infty$ and as a consequence in $c$ is a uniform convergence on $\mathbb{N}$

**Hint 2:** If $\{a^{(n)}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset c$ is a uniformly convergent sequence, then
$$
\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_i^{(n)}=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}a_i^{(n)}
$$

Comment: Since you use this construction frequently: It is [as **a** consequence](http://thesaurus.com/browse/as+a+consequence) or you could use *consequently*.

Comment: @Norbert ??? is this obvious?

Comment: Martin, thanks! Is this construction is not common in English?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva The first remark is indeed obvious. The second is standard result which you should be taught. This property is one of the reasons to pay attention to uniform convergence

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use it. It might sometimes be simpler to use something else (various synonyms are in the link).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots)\in \bar{c}$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $c$ such that $lim \ x_n = x$ and for each $n$ we write $x_n$ as $(\xi_1^n,\xi_2^n, \dots )$

Part 1)

By the definition of convergence and using the norm of $l^{\infty}$, we have that $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_0 \implies \|x_n - x \| = sup_{j\leq 1}  \ |\ \xi^n_j - \xi_j| < \epsilon/3$

Also for each fixed $j$ we have $| \xi^n_j - \xi_j| < \epsilon/3$.

Part 2)

Let $n=N_0$, $x_N \in c$ and in particular $x_N$ is a Cauchy sequence. So $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $j,k\geq N_1 \implies |\xi^N_j - \xi^N_k| < \epsilon/3$

Part 3)

Given $\epsilon >0$, taking $j,k \geq max{\{N_1, N_0}\}$

$|\xi_j - \xi_k| \leq |\xi_j - \xi^N_j| + |\xi^N_j - \xi^N_k| + |\xi^N_k - \xi_k| < \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon$

This proves $x$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Part 4)

$K =$ $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is complete AND $x \in K^\infty$ AND $x$ is a Cauchy sequence, therefore x converges, i.e., $x \in c$.

Equivalently, this proves that $c$ is a complete vector subspace of $l^\infty$.